# c# How can I bypass this issue without manipulating the GetEnumerator method?

Tags: c#, foreach, hashset

I want to use a foreach on an hashset but VS won't allow it.
This is what I have so far:

```
{
class Team
{
    private HashSet<HeroStats> team;



    public Team()
    {

    }
    public void add(HeroStats hero) {
        if (team.Count <= 5)
            team.Add(hero);
        else Console.WriteLine("Team is full , create another team");
    }

    public Team print(Team team) {
        List<HeroStats> l;
        foreach (HeroStats h in team)
            l.Add(h);
        return l;
    }
}
```

}

With this code VS says that the foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ConsoleApplication3.model.data.domain.Team' because 'ConsoleApplication3.model.data.domain.Team' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Comment: You need to initialise `l` otherwise there will be error when you call `Add` on it.

Comment: Rename your `private HashSet<HeroStats> team;` to `heroes` and your problem will become clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two conflicting `team` here; there is:

- `HashSet<HeroStats> team` (the field)
- `Team team` (the parameter)

The second takes precedence here, but you talk about "foreach on an hashset", so I'm guessing you mean to iterate the *field*:

```
foreach (HeroStats h in this.team)
        l.Add(h);
```

(although note that you never initialize `l` as a new list)

Or more simply:

```
return this.team.ToList();
```

However, note that neither of these use the `Team team` that is passed in.

Comment: He's passing in a `Team`, so maybe he wants `team.team`.

Comment: @Gabe could be... could be; only the OP knows for sure

Comment: @MarcGravell i think Gabe is right, the OP confused his self by bad variable naming

Comment: I've corrected the errors. The solution indeed got pretty fuzzy from the naming of the parameters, sorry for that. I've also noticed that the return type was wrong since the method was of type Team and the returned value was of type List. 
Thank you !